# Postgres error: portal "C_n" does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql

I've been trying to track down a postgres error log that came from a legacy Java application and I'm having difficulty understanding this error message (where `n` is a number)

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: portal "C_n" does not exist
```

From what I've read online it has something to do with a cursor although on initial review I do not see a cursor being used.

Can someone shed some light on what the error means and why it would occur?

For background context, I've identified that suspect code does the following

1. Starts at transaction
2. Queries the DB for a single item (select * from blah limit 1) (error is thrown here)

Comment: Best bet at this point is to `tail` the Postgres log to see what it says.

Comment: The error might be suggesting that you _do_ need to use a cursor